# CsvToBean equivalent for apache-commons-csv?

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-beanutils, apache-commons-csv

I've read about a dozen tutorials showing how to use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and [apache-commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) to parse CSV files. That's all nice and works for me. But one thing always catches my attention: OpenCSV has the `CsvToBean` untility class which makes it so nice to convert CSV data to Java POJOs. I couldn't find the equivalent von `CsvToBean` in `apache-commons-csv`, though I think that the API of `apache-commons-csv` is more clearly structured and thus it's more intuitive for me to use it.

How to comfortably convert a CSV record read with `apache-commons-csv` to a bean? Sure, I can simply set every field manually. But that's not comfortable. It looks ugly and it's a code smell. When a field is added or removed it would result in one more place where I have to adjust the code, so it would increase the maintenance workload.

Idea: Can I use `apache-commons-beanutils` in a similar fashion as CsvToBean to convert CSV data to Java POJOs, or what other way is there to do this?

Comment: Get field names by reflection, loop through them and use `field.set(bean,csvRecord.get(field.getName()));` to set the value

Comment: In short the answer is no, not out of the box